# .htaccess Rewrite URL same page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**I want to rewrite the following URLs:**

```
localhost/beta/coupons.php?cat=promotions point to ---> localhost/beta/coupons/promotions


localhost/beta/coupons.php?city=ny point to ---> localhost/beta/coupons/ny
```

I run this code in .htaccess

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase  /beta/


RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^coupons/([^/]*)$ coupons.php?cat=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^coupons/([^/]*)$ coupons.php?city=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^coupons/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ coupons.php?cat=$1&city=$2 [L]

</IfModule>
```

The code only runs the first re writing, the second does not work.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: The second one won't work because it is never called. And it is never called because the patterns are identical.  Perhaps use `coupons/cat/promotions/` and `coupons/city/ny` instead.

Comment: I wanted to use both the same patterns to improve seo, but I see that is not possible.

Is there any way to keep the same patterns?

Comment: If `city` is generally two characters, then you can use `^coupons/([a-z]{2})$ coupons.php?city=$1`.

Comment: `city` is set of a database field, this field contains the slug.
Example slug `los-angeles`

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're going to have to specify the difference to Apache.